# Extending TreeMap in Kotlin fails lint

Tags: android, kotlin, lint

Not sure if this is a bug or I have an issue with my implementation in Kotlin.

I extended TreeMap:

```
class TargetTreeMap : TreeMap<String, Target>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER) {...)
```

After running lint, I get `NewApi` lint errors on my class:

`13: Call requires API level 24 (current min is 19): java.util.TreeMap#getOrDefault`

`13: Call requires API level 24 (current min is 19): java.util.TreeMap#remove`

EDIT:
I forgot to mention that I am not using those methods in my implementation.

Comment: which Kotlin version are you using? Looks like the linter is not working well with the bytecode generated by kotlin. I've seen several issues like this being addressed by the Kotlin team.

Comment: Just upgraded to 1.1.4-3

Comment: This looks like the following issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-20302, could you please add your case there?